# data appending as dataframe in memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like this
df:

```
,load,mem,Loc,Rem
0,1.0,7.48,6.7,pencil
1,1.0,8.020022,7.602671,book
```

df1:

```
0,log_no
1,1.2165430890794655
```

which I am appending at each iteration and it attaches like below with command

```
    df.to_csv(out_path,  mode='a', header=True)
    df1.to_csv(out_path,  mode='a', header=True)
```

and it results as csv below:

```
,load,mem,Loc,Rem
0,1.0,7.48,6.7,pencil
1,1.0,8.020022,7.602671,book
0,log_no
1,1.2165430890794655
```

Than, I have to import it again with

```
pd.read_csv()
```

I want to keep it appended as dataframe as df3 in memory to use it further instead of exporting and importing again. Is it possible?
I tried to append several ways, but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! Just use `.append()` method:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
```

And then, inside loop:

```
df3 = df3.append(df)
df3 = df3.append(df1)
```

Comment: it throws error as NameError: name 'df3' is not defined

Comment: @ML85 I've just edited an answer, check it out

Comment: There is no error, but no data with that df3.

Comment: It has little issue. It appends but the data in next iteration is updated and not get written below as expected as I do and export in csv.

Comment: If with this solution, there comes any option which adds data of each iteration and not replace would be my solution. any recommendation

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you cannot store dataframe they way you provided in your example. I would suggest you using two different dataframes: One with `load,mem,Loc,Rem` columns, and another with `log_no` column in order to make dataframes consistent and reusable

Comment: Sure, just like in your example. Just saving this dataframes with `mode='a'` flag to `.csv` file